# How do I ask for the input of a variable when needed instead of typing input() before every line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I make it so if this variable is needed, it'll ask for the input of this variable?

```
"""imports"""
import math
"""def"""
def rectArea:
    return A = l * b
def rectPeri:
    return P = 2 * (l+b)
def squareArea:
    return A = l*l
def squarePeri:
    return P = l * 4
def parallelogramArea:
    return A = l * h
def parallelogramPeri:
    return P = 2 * (l+b)
```

For example in `rectArea`, length(`l`) and breadth(`b`) are needed, so it would ask for an input of the `l` and `b` variables?

Comment: So you want to try the `return`, capture any `NameError`s and then prompt the user to input? That could be quite tricky. Probably better practice just to define the  variables as inputs for the functions

Comment: I think you're going about this entirely the wrong way. in rectArea function, the names `l` and `b` are *always* needed. If you're not passing these to the function as arguments, then you *always* need to ask for input using `input` function.

Answer (score 0):

For user input use the `input()` method.

```
length = input("Enter rectangle length: ")
```